# Linking two UITableViews

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview

I have two UITableViews and I want that when the user moves the one, then the other one moves too.

I tried implementing this by overloading `scrollViewDidScroll:` and calling the parallell view and make it perform its move programatically..

The problem here is that when the one table views crolls and I programmatically set the he contentOffset of the other one, then the one moved programmatically does not refresh its UI making it look like its cut off when swiping the table.

Answer (score 2):

That’s kind of an odd solution, and you’re not going to have much luck with the `-scrollViewDidScroll:` approach—if you really must use two separate table views, then you’re probably best off overriding `-touchesBegan:withEvent:`, `-touchesMoved:withEvent:` and `-touchesEnded:withEvent:`, and passing those events over to the other table view (probably with an offset position for each of the `UITouch` objects involved).

If at all possible, though, you should implement it as a single table view, with cells that’re laid out to look like two columns (assuming that’s the appearance you’re going for). It’ll be more efficient and save you a lot of headache.